# Python Numpy Dictionary Map Import?

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, 2d, tile

So i want to try and use a numpy array to import a 2D map file to display graphical tiles on a grid. So say I have a window that takes 5x10 tiles. I'be been able to let the '1's represent a certain PNG tile in a dictionary, but how would i import a map file with other numbers and even symbols like $ or % or @ ect inside my dictionary instead of just all the 1s?

```
>>> numpy.ones((10,5))
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>>
```

Comment: What is the format of your "map file"?

Comment: It would just be an array of keys. Like in the above 1: cool.png, 2: other.png. Question is how do I get to make up my own array instead of just having 1s.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to create a large image by tiling a set of smaller images, then Python Image Library  (PIL) is what you should use.

Also, supposing you want to put the names of the files inside the array, thus creating an array of strings instead of an array of ones, you could loop over like this:

```
for row in xrange(a.shape[0]):
    for column in xrange(a.shape[1]):
        final_image.paste(tiledict[a[row, column]], row*tilesize, column*tilesize)
```

In the above code, `final_image` would be a large `pil.Image` object where you paste each tile, and `tiledict` is the dictionary from where you take these images from.

Hope this helps!